# How to overcome this stack overflow issue when finding SCCs?

Tags: java, version-control, stack-overflow, microsoft-distributed-file-system, kosaraju-algorithm

This is the code I wrote to find SCCs usigng Kosaraju's Two-Passed Algorithm. When I run the main method, I get a StackOverFlowError on SCC.revDFS. How can I avoid the stack overflow error when having a large amount of recursive calls?

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SCC {
    int n = 875714;
    Map<Integer,List<Integer>> adjList;
    Map<Integer,List<Integer>> adjListRev;
    int[] ft;
    int t;
    int s;
    boolean[] marked;
    int[] leaders;

    public SCC() {
        init();
        t = 0;
        s = 0;
        marked = new boolean[n + 1];
        leaders = new int[n + 1];
    }

    void init() {
        adjList = new HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>>();
        adjListRev = new HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>>();
        ft = new int[n + 1];
        List<Integer> adj;
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner (new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().
                    getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("SCC.txt")));
            while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String s = scanner.nextLine().trim();
                String[] num = s.split(" ");
                if (!adjList.containsKey(Integer.parseInt(num[0]))) {
                    adjList.put(Integer.parseInt(num[0]), new ArrayList<Integer>());
                }
                adj = adjList.get(Integer.parseInt(num[0]));
                adj.add(Integer.parseInt(num[1]));
                adjList.put(Integer.parseInt(num[0]), adj);

                if (!adjListRev.containsKey(Integer.parseInt(num[1]))) {
                    adjListRev.put(Integer.parseInt(num[1]), new ArrayList<Integer>());
                }
                adj = adjListRev.get(Integer.parseInt(num[1]));
                adj.add(Integer.parseInt(num[0]));
                adjListRev.put(Integer.parseInt(num[1]), adj);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void DFS_Loop() {

        for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++) {
            marked[i] = false;
        }
        for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
            if (!marked[i]) {
                revDFS(i);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++) {
            marked[i] = false;
            leaders[i] = 0;
        }
        for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
            if (!marked[ft[i]]) {
                s = ft[i];
                DFS(ft[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    public void revDFS(int i) {
        marked[i] = true;
        List<Integer> edges = adjListRev.get(i);
        if (edges != null) {
            for (int j: edges) {
                if (!marked[j]) {
                    revDFS(j);
                }
            }
        }
        t += 1;
        ft[t] = i;
    }

    public void DFS(int i) {
        marked[i] = true;
        leaders[s] += 1;
        List<Integer> edges = adjList.get(i);
        if (edges != null) {
            for (int j: edges) {
                if (!marked[j]) {
                    DFS(j);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SCC scc = new SCC();
        scc.DFS_Loop();
        Arrays.sort(scc.leaders);
        for (int i = scc.n; i < scc.n - 5; i--) {
            System.out.println(scc.leaders[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to convert the logic to iterative approach. Also, do check if you have base and edge cases handled properly.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea for converting a recursive function into an iterative function is that a recursive function consumes arguments from a stack.

So you can create a stack and push the values into it and then consume them in a loop.

```
public void _revDFS(int _i) {
    LinkedList<Integer> stack = new LinkedList<>();
    stack.push(_i);

    while(!stack.isEmpty()){
        int i = stack.pop();
        marked[i] = true;
        List<Integer> edges = adjListRev.get(i);
        if (edges != null) {
            for (int j: edges) {
                if (!marked[j]) {
                    stack.push(j);
                    //revDFS(j);
                }
            }
        }
        t += 1;
        ft[t] = i;
    }
}
```

I can't really test it to see if I made a mistake of some kind and `revDFS` is a function with a lot of side effect and it does not return a value, so is a bit difficult to reason with it.

But the gist is that instead of calling the function itself you can just push the edge indexes onto the stack and then consume them.

The child edges will be processed in reverse order so if you want to keep the same order of processing of the original you should read the edges in reverse order :

```
            ListIterator<Integer> li = edges.listIterator(edges.size());
            while(li.hasPrevious()){
                int j = li.previous();
                if (!marked[j]) {
                    stack.push(j);
                    //revDFS(j);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem of using a stack to avoid recursion is that the finishing time of each node would be incorrect. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

you have implemented your Dfs function recursively which causes "stack overflow". To overcome this issue you need to implement it using stack data structure. 
see link bellow for more motivations
https://github.com/sinamalakouti/MyFavoriteAlgorithmProblems